# AES Encryption With PBKDF2 KDF in pycrypto

Tags: aes

I am a bit new to encryption and I've seen a lot of recommendations to use a KDF for encryption and decryption. I'm a bit confused since I've been trying to encrypt the data using PBKDF2 algorithm and salt is generated using get_random_bytes, but when I try to decrypt the data I try to derive a new key using a new salt, this throws off my decryption. When I make the salt something constant for example b'salt' decryption works as expected but if I try to regenerate the salt and then regenerate the key the decryption doesn't work. My question is, should I be using the same salt for key derivation for encryption and decryption? Also if encryption happens on a server and decryption happens on the client, doesn't sending the salt over the network make using a KDF pointless? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: note: pycrypto (https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) is dead, unmaintained with multiple well known security vulnerabilities, if you need API compatibility look into pycryptodome (https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/), or pyca/cryptography (https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) if you do no not

Comment: I am using pycryptodome btw. I just call it pycrypto, force of habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick aside, something newer like [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), the 2015 password hashing competition winner, is better than PBKDF2. Using a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (KDF) and the same key to encrypt many messages (for example) isn't particularly secure. There are also methods of exchanging keys like [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) Key Exchange, although they may not be applicable in certain use-cases.

---

From re-reading your question, it seems you think a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) is a function that allows you to keep a shared secret key and generate (with random salt) the same derived key.  In which case the salt would have no effect whatsoever.

Note that PBKDF2 is built from a hash function.  In the case of [pycrypto](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/kdf.html) it is using HMAC-SHA512.  As such, the [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) needs to be the same in order for the derived key to be the same.

When you are generating a new salt, you are generating a different hashed key.  That is exactly why salt is used. [Actually, for deriving Multiple Keys can be risky with PBDKF2, once your password is found the two keys are gone.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75235/18298) You can use PBKDF2 to generate a key and then use KDF.

The purpose of the salt is to prevent against pre-computed attacks on the hash (eg. Rainbow-table).  See more [here](http://bugcharmer.blogspot.com/2012/06/passwords-matter.html).

Sending the salt over the network strengthens the KDF. As a simple example (I am the attacker):

**Without a salt**

I download a file with a list of all hashes for likely n character passwords.  I watch traffic and match many transmitted digests with my downloaded file.  I required internet, significant storage space, and network hacking skills.

**With a salt**

I cannot download (or generate) a file with all likely passwords as every password has too many possible hashes.  I watch traffic, and must generate a new hash file for every salt I see.

---

As you can see (hopefully), the salt makes it far more difficult to pre-compute anything before you see the salt.

Comment: The OP needs clarification since they tell that encrypt the data with PBKDF2. Also they need to know that for derive the same key that need the use the same salt again. In short, the confusion of the concepts.

Comment: @kelalaka I see what you mean now. Edited to clarify what PBKDF2 actually is.

Comment: I've updated some parts, reordered the head part, which was not smooth.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, seems simple enough. I see you mention Diffie-Hellman, I'm actually implementing a very simplified version of Kerberos, so the password is never sent over the network, hence why it's difficult to get the same salt. What happens in the Kerberos protocol is that the user sends their ID and the server uses their password stored on the database to encrypt a Ticket Granting Server ephemeral key. So what do you suggest I do to make encryption more secure?

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer.  [Here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4556) is the RFC relating to using Public Key cryptography for initial authentication in Kerberos. [Here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3962) is another on using AES for encryption.  You can find more on the Wiki page for the protocol.

Comment: Thanks mate  :).