Best way of using AES GCM with static key PBKDF2/HKDF
Refering to this thread : using different IV and SALT with AES-CBC but same KEY
I am in a similar situation to the one exposed, namely that I need to use AES to encrypt data, however, I cannot implement PBKDF2 correctly by having a unique key for each encryption because I cannot wait for the derivation time in terms of performance of my application.
So I came across this very interesting discussion, but I'm not sure I apply it correctly to my case.
Important point in my case, I can use AES GCM.
Do I understand the following correctly, which of those options are the right ones ?
Option A:

From a 16-character "strong" random passphrase composed of uppercase, lowercase, number and special characters, I derive a PBKDF2 key with a unique salt and 600k iterations. This will be my master key.

Then, for each cryptographic operation, Encrypt and Decrypt I derive an HKDF key from the Master Key, using a unique random salt this time.

I then use AES GCM with this new key, generating the unique nonce and tag and adding the HKDF salt. So the complete cipher will be composed of: Nonce (12B) | Ciphertext (*B) | Tag (16B) | HkdfSalt (32B)
Result, I use a unique key by encryption, even with a sufficiently high entropy because it was initially derived from PBKDF2.


Option B:
Same as A but no need to derive a new HKDF key each time with a different salt. A single fixed HKDF key even without salt would be sufficient.
Option C:
All this is overkill and simply using the fixed PBKDF2 master key is sufficient in the case of GCM?

Multiple AES Key Derivation from a master key

Thanks @kelalaka I just check this, the answer is very "cryptographic" :) Good thing but a bit complex for me. Can you please advice me and tell me if one of my listed option is the good one, or near the good one ? Thx

Option C is ok.

Can you use Argon2id or Scrypt? PBKDF2 is old and not well designed. What about the password generation process?

@kelalaka I have indeed seen that it is preferable to use Argon2 or Scrypt, however, I am in a C# context and I have not found an official implementation from Microsoft or at least from a recognized third party like Bouncy Castle and I'm obviously not able to implement it myself. There are many other smaller libraries, but I have no guarantee on their implementation.

Regarding the Password Generation Process, nothing too exotic, I have complete control over this process, from a secure session, from a 16-character "strong" random passphrase composed of uppercase, lowercase, number and special characters, I derive a PBKDF2 key with a unique salt and 600k iterations. The pass and key are then stored separately in a KeyVault.
@K.G. seems to say that option C is sufficient, for the moment I have implemented option B and I opened this question because I was wondering if we should not implement option A instead. I'm a little lost as a result :)

Your options A and B show some lack of knowledge. HKDF has an extract mechanism that extracts randomness from inputs and produces a Pseudo Random Key. Then with this key, one can generate many keys just using the info parameter. There is no need to mix PDKD2 and HKDF. I would go with HKDF, well your requirements are not clear, however, make sure that the strength of passwords are not less than 2^{128}.

@MarcAlves Functionality-wise, PBKDF2 is not good at generating long derived keys, which we fix by chaining with a simpler key derivation function. Security-wise, there are attacks that other pbkdfs resist better, but that may not be extremely important for you. Your option B, if I understand it correctly, adds nothing security- or functionality-wise to your option C, but it does not harm. Option A adds nothing, as far as I can tell. Obviously, I do not know your application. Also, if your passwords need not be human-memorable, why not generate proper keys?

@kelalaka I use HKDF because of this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75078, HKDF as a solution to mitigate the fact to have a fix PBKDF2 key, but I probably misunderstood. Now it is clear about the purpose of HKDF, and it is adding nothing more in my use case.  So I will go with option C, with a proper key as proposed by K.G. So, that's answer to my initial question, it is ok to have a fix static PBKDF2 I can reuse across encryptions with AES GCM.

@K.G. Very clear, I understand now why you confirmed the option C. About your point on password, that's true, no need to be human-memorable. When you say generate proper key, is something like that is what you mean : byte[] key = new byte[32]; using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) { rng.GetBytes(key); } Then use the base64 of this generated key to derive the final one with PBKDF2. Right ?

This question is missing important context. What type of application is this and how often does the user need to enter their password? To use Argon2, you can use libsodium or Monocypher. The official .NET crypto APIs are quite bad, including the one for AES-GCM, as some stuff isn't even cross-platform, among other problems. The answer to this question isn't simple without more info. For example, if you need lots of key material, it's a good idea to do PBKDF2 then HKDF because this allows more iterations.

A proper key means randomly generating the key as you describe (without Base64 encoding), except there's then no need to use PBKDF2 at all. You can then either randomly generate a unique key each time or use HKDF-Expand with different info to derive further keys from that initial random key. It sounds like you don't need to use passwords/strings and can probably do this instead.

@MarcAlves If you have a proper key, then, like samuel-lucas6 says, you do not need any pbkdf, nor any other kdf. Sometimes, you want to use a kdf to derive many keys in order to cryptographically separate different things, but to know whether that makes sense or not for you, we would have to know more about your application, which probably does not make sense for this place.

Indeed, this kind of question is never simple outside of the context and as @K.G. rightly says, this is not the right place to explain in detail. However, if it helps, my application performs data encryption with AES, the key is not entered by the user but shared and accessible to users via API from KeyVault (I'll spare you the details).

@samuel-lucas6 In addition, the application must have good performance, which is why initially we could not derive a unique key by cryptographic operation from a password with PBKDF2 because it was too long. So this returns to my initial use case, would AES GCM + a single random strong key for all operations be enough? I think I understood that a single static key is enough (my option C), so no need for PBKDF2 or HKDF?

You can use AES-GCM with a single key repeatedly as long as you're changing the nonce each encryption. Because the nonce is short, you should treat the nonce as a counter that gets incremented. If you were changing the key frequently, you could get away with randomly generating the nonce. There's also a limit on the length of a single message that you can encrypt due to an internal counter, but you're unlikely to reach that.

What are the rules for using AES-GCM correctly?

Could someone write an answer to this question? This deserves one though I don't like the question with titles including "best" like words.

Everything is clear to me now. Thanks for the clarification, I am sure it will helps other to better understand this topic !
